# How to change the background transparency of a standard system button

Tags: android, button, view, android-widget

I have a group of buttons in one of my activities. The buttons look fine as they come from the Android system(grey), as my activity's background is grey. I've tried the following

```
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(125, 200, 200, 200));
```

which creates the desired transparency but i lose the buttons states like pressed, up etc.

How can i keep the button's states that ship with android and only reduce opacity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your class, use code below:

```
alpha = new AlphaAnimation(0.3F, 0.3F); //Set opacity - Range 0.0 to 1.0
alpha.setDuration(0); // Set animation duration
alpha.setFillAfter(true); // Maintaining the effect to the button
yourButton.startAnimation(alpha);
```

I hope I helped.

Bye!

Comment: @Tanyna Bonaldo Yes you did help, awesome mate and just what i wanted thanks;)

Answer (score 0):

In the xml for the desired buttons, you should simply be able to put:

android:background="@android:color/transparent"

I used this to display the drawable without the default gray background.

-cheers

Comment: warning this will drop all background... there wont even be the outline since whole button image is in fact the background

Answer (score 0):

the dynamic way:

Button.getBackground(), usually it returns a BitmapDrawable if you set a bitmap as background, or ColorDrawable if you set color as background.
i.e.
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = (ColorDrawable) button.getBackground();
colorDrawable.setAlpha(125);

this would work fine.

the static way:
in layout, set background color like #7EC8C8C8

Comment: Hi, it does work, but is it the best way to use an animation to change the opacity? I think it would be better if you change the alpha channel of background drawable.